# Анимация фигуры на CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg

[image: Фигура]

Это png фигура находится в шапке сайта. Как можно реализовать плавное вращение коричневых кругов вокруг чёрного?
Я не прошу дать мне готовый код, просто подскажите, какой библиотекой JS воспользоваться. И возможно ли это вообще, не рисуя gif?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для таких задач можно использовать `SVG`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox=" -20 -20 600 600">
  <g>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="black"/>
    <circle cx="250" cy="100" r="25" fill="brown"/>
    <circle cx="72" cy="253" r="30" fill="brown"/>
    <circle cx="55" cy="71" r="35" fill="brown"/>
    <line x1="80" y1="95" x2="111" y2="120" stroke-width="10" stroke="gray"/> 
    <line x1="228" y1="111" x2="195" y2="128" stroke-width="10" stroke="gray"/> 
    <line x1="120" y1="190" x2="90" y2="230" stroke-width="10" stroke="gray"/> 
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, мой вечер наполнился смыслом)

Comment: @Danilka37, был рад помочь:)

Comment: @St1myL,  хорошо изобразил...

Answer (score 1):

На css мне кажется больше возможностей : для ознакомления

```css
.items {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  animation: scale 5s linear infinite;
  z-index: 100;
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(.9)rotate(-10deg);
  }
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  position: absolute;
}

.item1 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  animation: color 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  10% {
    background: darkblue;
  }
  50% {
    background: blue;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.1)
  }
}

.item1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: %;
  z-index: -3;
  transform: rotate(55deg);
}

.item2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -35px;
  animation: key 6s linear;
}

@keyframes key {
  10% {
    transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    background: #444;
  }
}

.item2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 90%;
  z-index: -2;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.item3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: -50px;
  animation: drive 2s linear infinite;
}

.item3:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -10;
  transform: rotate(-9deg);
}

@keyframes drive {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10px, 0);
  }
  30% {}
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MVKzQd?editors=1100 мои экспирименты

Comment: попробую и этот вариант, спасибо!